# Docker Push Error with Invalid Tag or Reference

Tags: docker, travis-ci, treescale

I have a Travis CI build that is attempting to push to a docker registry and here is what I see in the build logs:

```
[info] Built image repo.treescale.com/[secure]/inland24/plant-simulator:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

But the next line, I get to see the following:

```
Error parsing reference: "/:" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

This is what I have as my docker push command:

```
docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/$APPLICATION_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION_DEV;
```

And here are the parameters:

```
   - APPLICATION_NAME    = [secure]/inland24/plant-simulator
   - IMAGE_VERSION_DEV   = 1.0-SNAPSHOT
   - DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL = repo.treescale.com
```

Assume that [secure] is resolved to a proper username! What is this error that I get and how to solve it?

I did try to list out all the images and I can see that my image exists on the local machine where the build is being run:

```
REPOSITORY                                           TAG                      IMAGE ID            CREATED                  SIZE
repo.treescale.com/[secure]/inland24/plant-simulator   1.0-SNAPSHOT             34842cf7482e        Less than a second ago   225 MB
anapsix/alpine-java                                  8_server-jre_unlimited   bd197f461851        11 days ago              124 MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error clearly suggest what's wrong. You are using

```
docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/$APPLICATION_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION_DEV;
```

Error parsing reference: "/:" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format

If I blank all the environment variables then I get

```
docker push /:
```

Which gives me the same error. Use a env command before the docker push and make sure your environment variables are actually present or not. If not then figure out why

Comment: Yep! That seems like a bug from travis - The environment variables are not getting passed on! i have created an issue with travis ci - https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8231

Answer (score 1):

The brackets are not permitted.

From https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/api.md:

> A repository name is broken up into path components. A component of a
>   repository name must be at least one lowercase, alpha-numeric
>   characters, optionally separated by periods, dashes or underscores.
>   More strictly, it must match the regular expression
>   [a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*

Comment: The brackets are not given by me, but rather I have the username and password configured accordingly in my Travis CI!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by moving the bit that does the docker push outside of the jobs description as shown below in my yml snippet:

```
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: test
      script: sbt clean coverage test coverageReport
    - stage: build docker image
      script:
        - if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" ]; then
            sbt docker:publishLocal;
            docker images;
          fi

after_script:
  - if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" ]; then echo "Completed building docker image";
      docker login -u $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL;
      docker push $DOCKER_APP_NAME;
    fi
  - echo $TRAVIS_BRANCH
```

So earlier I had the docker login and docker push commands within the jobs stage script and I moved it out of that into an after script which did the trick!